# How to calculate DateTime fields in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following Date time fields and I would like to calculate the total time between them. Which is the best approach?

```
session_end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
discharged_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
checked_in_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: The `-` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `DateTime` Fields are like `datetime` object of python, to calculate the total time between, you need to substract one from another one since they are same objects. This is an approach

```
result = datetime1 - datetime2
result.seconds # To have the output in seconds
```

In your case:

```
total_time = (checked_in_at - discharged_at).seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `-` operator to calculate the time difference. The result will be a `time delta` object.

```
def time_diff(time1, time2):
    "retun time2-time1 in 'seconds' "
    if time1 and time2:
        return (time2 - time1).seconds
    return "one of the input is None"
```

This function returns the difference in seconds and it  will handle `TypeError` exception if one of the input is a `None` type. (
You defined it as `null=True` in `models`)